# 海が油まみれにになってしまった and 海の鳥たちが油まみれになってしまった

Tags: grammar

タンカーの事故で油が流れ出して、(A)海が油まみれになってしまった。

タンカーの事故で油が流れ出して、(B)海の鳥たちが油まみれになってしまった。

The answer is (B).

Why is (A) not usable too ?

I saw this sentence “ 美しいビーチやダイビングスポットが油まみれになっている。”
ビーチ and ダイビングスポット can be used with 油まみれ.
But why can’t 海 in “(A)海が油まみれになってしまった。” be used with 油まみれになってしまった。

Edited : I saw the sentence “アフリカの島国　モーリシャスの海が油まみれ” too. So, I became to think the point isn’t 海 with 油まみれ anymore, but I still don’t know why is (A) not correct too.

Comment: Is it asking which of A and B is correct? Then you can just think it's a bad question.

Comment: Yes, it is. So, this means both choices are usable ? 
Thanks a lot. Been stuck with this question for hours.

Comment: The person who created this question may have thought that for まみれる to be correct something has to be completely covered and 海 is too large for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まみれる refers to the condition where most of the surface of something is dirtied by substances like mud. It is typically used for relatively small objects, such as living creatures or boats. It might also be applicable to a beach, which is solid and comparatively small.

What if it's used with the sea? If the contaminant was a substance like mercury that dissolves in water, using まみれる would be completely incorrect. Since it's oil in this case, it's possible to interpret it as "adhering to the surface of the sea", and many people might not see it as a problem. Still, "a liquid being まみれる with another liquid" is not the most typical usage of まみれる. When asked on a test like this, it's easy to choose the correct answer.